# Android image processing get image data quick

Tags: android, image

I am creating an Android app to do some image processing techniques with the camera and it needs to be fast. This is the pseudo-code of how the entire system works:

```
1. loop while not finished
   1.1 get image frame
   1.2 process image for object detection
2. end loop
```

I actually have questions on the basics of the `Camera` class:

1. Is previewing the perceived image from the camera faster than no previews at all? The former means using `SurfaceView` to preview the image.
2. Let's say from the `takePicture()` method, can the image data array be obtained without the previews?

My real question is, what is the best way to obtain the image data (say, `byte[]` array) quickly and iteratively after processing the image (as stated on top)?

I planned to use `takePicture()` method to get the image data, but I need your opinion if this is the only way or if there other better ways.

Comment: You could probably use preview mostly. A call to takePicture will capture at full Res and take some time to process before your code actualy gets it. Some apps use a combination of both. Do very quick stuff with preview frames and overall expensive computations on the frames obtained from takePicture.

Comment: How do you get the preview frames? A simple code snippet will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a SurfaceView as the Camera's preview display and get the data of every preview frame using the PreviewCallback. This would be better than using takePicture if you don't need the high resolution that takePicture captures. In other words, if you want to capture images of lower quality at a faster rate, use PreviewCallback... if you want to capture images of higher quality at a very slow rate, use takePicture.

As for your questions, I don't think you can take pictures without using a preview display, but i could be wrong.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PreviewCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback  {
  ...

  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)  {
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    ...
  }

  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // image data contained in data... do as you wish
  }
}
```